# Saving using File output stream from Edittext in only one file

Tags: android, android-edittext, fileoutputstream

kindly i need to save from edit text to a file or list using file output stream, however each time I save with name written in the edit text a new file is created, how can I make an only one file and each time I enter data in the edit text it updates the same file only.

Also how can I add counters to the file

```
Button save;
EditText Username, ID;
String FILENAME, JOUR;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.internal);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);
    Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

}



@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FILENAME = Username.getText().toString();
    if (FILENAME.contentEquals("")){
        finish();
    }
    JOUR = ID.getText().toString();

    Username.setText("");
    ID.setText("");

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME , Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(JOUR.getBytes());
    //  fos.write(FILENAME.getBytes());
        fos.close();

         Toast.makeText(
                   InternalStore.this,
                   FILENAME + " saved",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: why is a new file created ? probably because you, like, create a new file ?

Comment: no I take the name from the edit text, so every name I enter makes a new file

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BufferedWriter out=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(getFilesDir()+File.separator+fileName.getText().toString()+".txt"));

out.write(text.getText().toString());
out.close();
```